# I am trying to convert ARM Template to Bicep using Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

When I am trying to convert json to bicep by using PowerShell It throws an error and dropped a link below

[image]

Is there any alternate method to convert json to bicep

I tried and got an error as mentioned above. And trying for an alternate method.

Comment: we can convert `Json` to `bicep` using VS Code. save Json code in a file and open the folder in `VS Code`. After that press `ctrl+p` it will open a command palette in that use the following command `>bicep:decompile to bicep` . it will convert `json` to bicep and create a`.bicep` file in the same directory.

Comment: Please copy errors instead of screenshotting them. This helps other people to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

- I have converted the `Json` to `Bicep` using **VS Code**.
- Follow the below steps
- Create a folder and save your `Json` template in that folder. After that open **VS Code** and GOTO **files** on the left corner -> Click on **Select Folder** -> Select the folder Which you have created in the **VS Code**
- After that press `Ctrl+P` it will open a command palette then search for  `>Bicep: decompile to Bicep` as below

[image]

- It will convert `json` to bicep and create a`.bicep` file in the same directory.

[image]